# Would like to textbox to show message when cell values are unequal

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I am working on an userform and user needs to enter the same amount but in  different breakdowns for three times. I would like to create a textbox that can alert user in realtime if the amount is equal in those three areas.

My simple logic and code is stated below:

Sum of 1st breakdown - Sum of 2nd breakdown - Sum of 3rd breakdown = 0 means true.

Got it work finally!

```
Private Sub CheckSum1()

'Sum of 1st - 3rd breakdown
On Error Resume Next
Me.CCTotal = (IIf(Me.Cash.Value = vbNullString, 0, Me.Cash) + 0) + (IIf(Me.CCash.Value = vbNullString, 0, Me.CCash) + 0) - (IIf(Me.TotalBox1 = vbNullString, 0, Me.TotalBox1) + 0)

End Sub

Private Sub CheckSum()

'Sum 2nd break down - 3rd breakdown
On Error Resume Next
Me.Test = (IIf(Me.MCash.Value = vbNullString, 0, Me.MCash) + 0) + (IIf(Me.PCash.Value = vbNullString, 0, Me.PCash) + 0) - (IIf(Me.TotalBox1 = vbNullString, 0, Me.TotalBox1) + 0)

End Sub


Private Sub CheckTotal_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

'Use a label to check if both are 0
If (IIf(Me.Test.Value = vbNullString, 0, Me.Test) + 0) And (IIf(Me.CCTotal.Value = vbNullString, 0, Me.CCTotal) + 0) <> 0 Then
CheckTotal.Caption = "Match"
Finish.Enabled = False
Else
    CheckTotal.Caption = "Unmatch"
    Finish.Enabled = True
    End If

 End Sub

Private Sub CCtotal_Change()

Call CheckSum
Call CheckSum1

End Sub

Private Sub TotalBox1_Change()

Call CheckSum
Call CheckSum1

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your actual problem?

Comment: You can't change `CheckTotal` in the `CheckTotal_Change` handler; doing so will cause it to change again, which fires the event again, which causes it to change again, which fires the event again, etc. Common sense should tell you that won't work, right?

Answer (score 0):

since you only need to notify the user, use a `Label` control instead of a `TextBox` one (you can keep naming it after `CheckTotal`), so that you don't even need to disable it (a user can't edit a label control)

then write:

```
If (CDbl(MCash.Text) + CDbl(PCash.Text)) - (CDbl(Cash.Text) + CDbl(CCash.Text)) - (CDbl(SubTypeCash1.Text) + CDbl(SubTypeCash2.Text) + CDbl(SubtypeCash3.Text)) = 0 Then
    CheckTotal.Caption = "Match!"
Else
    CheckTotal.Caption = "NOT Match!"
End If
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your kind input, for some reasons the code works with no error, but the label just shows nothing, is there something I need to turn on for the label to update in real time? I tried to make a simple statement like this: if one textbox.value is <> 0 then label.caption = "Y" Else "N", but not a single change.

Comment: which sub did you put that code in? What's the name of the label?